# Migrating from NGINX to AngularCLI

Tags: angular, typescript, nginx, angular-cli

I have been using Nginx for my angular2 application. now I decided to migrate to the angular-CLI server. I am facing issues with setting cookies

In Nginx, I use proxy_cookie_path to define cookie path. how to do this in angular CLI

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name "a2distribution-local.com";
        location / {
                root /Users/mypc/Documents/angular2Distribution/ ;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
                }
        location /rest/ {
                       proxy_set_header Host $host;
                       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                       proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/cloudface/;
                       proxy_cookie_path /cloudface/  /;
               }
             }
```

How to achieve this configuration in angular CLI.

Comment: Angular-CLI is a **development-only** server. It's not indended for production.

Comment: yeah, that I got it. I want these setup for development only. In production I still use Nginx.

Comment: @JBNizet. any ideas. how to implement that

Comment: Why would you have to set cookies from the angular cli server? How could you? All it does is serve your static assets (images, generated JS bundles, index.html). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have an authentication system based on the cookie. how could I test without setting a cookie? can angular CLI server   store a cookie?

Comment: What I don't understand is why you don't set the cookie from that authentication system. What does angular-cli has to do with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular Cli uses [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy) which inherently uses [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#options) for proxy  the hood.

take a look at the provided options for [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#options). I don't see any options that suit your need. However, this may be helpful for others.

For proxy examples, take a look at examples in the cli wiki:

1. [using-corporate-proxy](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-using-corporate-proxy)
2. [proxy to back-end](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy)

Comment: currently, I am using '' document.cookie" as a hotfix to store my cookie.